# messaging endpoint in bot framework in vnet : outbound

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I wanna use Azure Bot Service and secure the the messaging endpoint by adding it to a vnet. Is Azure Bot Services able to use VNET for Outbound? The Channel (MS Teams via link) breaks as soon as I disable public access on the message endpoint.

Example: samplebot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
I've added this endpoint to a vnet_1 and attached a private link. The endpoint es reachable via a virtual machine from within the vnet, and blocked from the internet as desired.

[image]

In Azure Bot Service, I've created 2 Private Endpoints under "Networking". Both are linked to the vnet_1

[image]

I set the Disable public access and use private access flag. Well I hope? The flag is a but hard to understand.

[image]

I did not change the Messaging endpoint configuration, as I expect(?) that the URL wont change as soon as Azure Bot Services uses the VNET for Outbound traffic. From the VM inside vnet_1 the url: samplebot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages still works.

Question is:
Is Azure Bot Services using the VNET for Outbound?
Maybe some setting which is not doable via the blades is missing?
The Channel breaks as soon as I disable public access on the message endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the linked explanation, I figured it out.

Once public access to the messaging endpoint (azure web app) is disabled, all channels to the Azure Bot Services break except the direct line channel.

I used Postman to confirm that the connection still works after disabling public access.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1419179/bot-service-unable-to-call-api-thats-deployed-as-a

If you want to open teams channel in addition, you can do via a firewall rule:
[image]

The IP Adress range: 52.112.0/14 & 52.122.0/15 is MS Teams